# Java print two lines together

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to print a message on the screen and after that, take a value from the keyboard. i have 4 prints in a row but i have scan methods between them. When i run my code, the first two prints run together and i can't insert a value at the first variable, after the first print.

```
case 1:
            System.out.println("###Book Data###");
            System.out.print("Name of the book:\t");
            String Name = key.nextLine();

            System.out.print("ISBN of the book:\t");
            String ISBN = key.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Author of the book:\t");
            String author = key.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Copies of the book:\t");
            int copies = key.nextInt();
            book Book = new book(ISBN,Name,author,copies);
            lib.AddBook(Book);
            break;


#########Text Printed######
Please enter your selection:    1
###Book Data###
Name of the book:       ISBN of the book:
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the line above your `switch` statement has `key.nextInt()`  <sup>*</sup>.

The scanner reads the integer, but it leaves the end-of-line character `'\n'` in the buffer. You need to consume that `'\n'` character somehow, before the `key.nextLine();` inside the switch statement returns some relevant data to you.

To fix this problem, insert

```
key.nextLine();
```

in front of the `switch` statement.

<sup>*</sup> don't ask me how I know that :-)

Comment: Yes that works! Can u please explain me why that happens or what to search to find out the solution of the problem?

Comment: @Seekerakos `Scanner` keeps a "pointer" to the keyboard input buffer. When users type things, characters get into the buffer. When you read from the scanner, characters get removed from the buffer. You ask the user to enter a menu option; he presses `1`, then hits `[Enter]`. Your code reads `nextInt()` from the scanner, taking `'1'`. The `[Enter]` is still there. Now you ask for `nextLine()` inside the `case` statement. `Scanner` sees the `[Enter]`, so it returns you an empty line right away!

Comment: if i had insert key.close(); it ll do the same thing as i instert key.nextLine(); before my switch ?

Comment: @Seekerakos No, it wouldn't be the same, because if you try to read anything after a call to `close()` you get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

println makes a new line while print does not.  You should consider either using println, flushing the buffer, or calling a new line escape character "\n"