# Lines are combined when they're supposed to be separated

Tags: java

So I have my code compile but when I run it it combines my lines

```
System.out.print("Enter ID Number");
double ID=s.nextDouble();
if(ID >9999|| ID<0)
    ID=0;

System.out.print("Enter Make of Vehicle");
String make=s.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter Model of Vehicle");
String model=s.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter Color of Vehicle");
String color=s.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter Year");
double year=s.nextDouble();
if(year <2000 || year>2017)
    year=0;
```

When I run the program it combines the lines to say
`enter make of vehicle enter model of vehicle`
How do I stop this as they are supposed to be separate entries

Comment: try use `System.out.println`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java print two lines together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301754/java-print-two-lines-together)

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`

Comment: it still combines them, just puts it on 2 separate lines

Comment: Yes - I was too hasty - PoprostuRonin is probably right:)

Answer (score 0):

Put `s.nextLine()` after reading double. The problem is that `s.nextDouble();` does not consume new line character, so `s.nextLine();` after `System.out.println("Enter Make of Vehicle");` is called automatically, you don't see anything more because there is only this one new line character (and it is being consumed).

```
double ID=s.nextDouble();
s.nextLine();
if(ID >9999|| ID<0)
    ID=0;
```

Second thing is to replace `System.out.print` with `System.out.println` to print output in new line.

Answer (score 0):

Call `s.nextLine()` after `double ID=s.nextDouble()`, couse `nextDouble()` doesn't consume the `\n`